# Need Help Understanding Proof by Contradiction for Halting Problem

Tags: proof-techniques, halting-problem

I understand what the halting problem describes, but I do not understand how the proof by contradiction associated with it proves that it is impossible to solve.

The proof by contradiction can be defined as having a function Halt() which could determine whether a program will halt. One could then call this function in a program called Program and halt if the program halts or otherwise loop forever.

```
Program (String x)

If Halt(x, x) then
 Loop Forever
Else Halt.

END
```

What I don't understand is why if Halt() returns true that it has to Loop forever. Why can't the Program return 0 or 1?

Thanks

Comment: It loops forever, by construction, *so that* there is a contradiction. If it returned 0, then it is possible that the Halt() call will simply return True (for all we know) so that no contradiction happens. In other words, it is constructed to cover both cases (of Halt() returning True *or* False).

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I instead did if Halt(x,x) then return 0, why would this not be valid?

Comment: The program would be okay, but the proof wouldn't work (if Halt returns True, no contradiction arises since the program will indeed terminate). See https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/38477/73821 for a proof sketch.